# AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer is pink on iPhone XR

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation, avcapturesession, avcapturedevice

We have an AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer that should display the Camera image.
On iPhone 10 (and iPhone 7), the image is displayed correctly.
However on iPhone XR it is displayed in pink.

Here is my code how I setup the Camera Session:

```
UIView* scanView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:[self view].frame];
[self setCameraScanView:scanView];
[[self cameraScanView]setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
[self setScanCaptureSession:[[AVCaptureSession alloc] init]];
[[self scanCaptureSession]setSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPresetLow];
AVCaptureDevice* camera = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
AVCaptureVideoDataOutput* videoOutput = [[AVCaptureVideoDataOutput alloc] init];
[[videoOutput connectionWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo]setEnabled:YES];
[videoOutput setAlwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames:YES];
[videoOutput setSampleBufferDelegate:self
        queue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
[[self scanCaptureSession]addOutput:videoOutput];
NSError* error;
AVCaptureDeviceInput* input = [[AVCaptureDeviceInput alloc]
        initWithDevice:camera error:&error];
[[self scanCaptureSession]addInput:input];
if(error) {
    NSLog(@"There was an error setting up Device Input!");
}
AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer* previewLayer = [[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc]initWithSession:[self scanCaptureSession]];
[self setCameraLayer:previewLayer];
[[self cameraLayer] setContentsFormat:kCAContentsFormatRGBA16Float];
[[self cameraLayer] setOpaque:YES];
CALayer* rootLayer = [[self cameraScanView]layer];
[[self cameraLayer]setFrame:[self cameraScanView].bounds];
[[self cameraLayer]setVideoGravity:AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill];
[rootLayer addSublayer:[self cameraLayer]];
[[self scanCaptureSession]commitConfiguration];
[[self view] addSubview:[self cameraScanView]];
```

Here is an image how it looks on iPhone XR.
[image]

Comment: Why are you setting the layer's `contentsFormat` to `kCAContentsFormatRGBA16Float`?

Comment: @FrankSchlegel it doesnt matter which format i supply

Comment: Have you tried _not_ setting a format?

Comment: @FrankSchlegel Yes, I've added this line because i thought the format was the problem. but both setting the format and not setting it result in the pink image

Comment: Are the sample buffers you receive from the `videoOutput` also pink?

Comment: How do I check this?

Comment: You could set a break point in the `captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:` delegate method and inspect the incoming sample buffer with Quick Look (select it in the Variables View and hit space).

Comment: It is not pink there!
I couldnt inspect the sample Buffer directly though and I had to do this:
`CVImageBufferRef imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);
    CIImage* image = [CIImage imageWithCVImageBuffer:imageBuffer];`

The CIImage is not pink.

Comment: That's good because that means the preview layer is faulty somehow (and not the whole camera feed)...

Comment: But only on certain devices?